# Why python overwrites key value pair

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am adding dictionary in list but after addition all the dictionary have the same values. What is wrong in the below code

```
final_data=[]
print(type(final_data))
thisdict =  {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
}

thisdict["year"] = 2018
final_data.append(thisdict)
thisdict["year"]=2019
final_data.append(thisdict)

print(final_data)
```

In final_data there are two dictionary pair but 2018 is no where visible. Both dictionary have the 2019 values.

This is what I actually want in my code

```
qs=Member.objects.all()
for elem in qs:
    for v in elem:
        final_data.append(
            {"field_name": v, "field_type": Member._meta.get_field(v).get_internal_type()})
```

I am not able to get the field_data which queryset qs have.

Comment: just asking to understand you knowledge -> do you know what are references in general

Comment: @ashish singh it is : accessing the original value, i.e where it is stored.

Comment: yes, that is how you can understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the functionality of dictionaries, if you update on the same key, then it's previous value will be overwritten. In your case when you are reassigning the dictionary, the same is reflected in all other references. If you want to append different dictionaries in a list then you can something like below:

```py
final_data=[]

final_data.append({
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 2018
})
final_data.append({
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 2019
})
```

The above will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You're mutating the same dict. Try instead:

```
for year in [2018, 2019]:
    final_data.append({
        "brand": "Ford",
        "model": "Mustang",
        "year": year
    })
```

Comment: All the other answers focus only on "dicts only have unique keys", instead of the non-obvious but real issue of updating the same dict. +1

Comment: This is just an example what I am trying to achieve. I am getting data from database into a queryset. I want to create a data structure which gives me output in following patterns data={"field_name":<field_name>, "field_type":<field_type>,"field_value":<data from database>}

Comment: @Akash ok, and where is the problem?

Comment: I am able to get the field_name and field_type but not the field_value in a single loop. following is the code     for elem in qs:
        for v in elem:
            final_data.append(
                {"field_name": v, "field_type": Member._meta.get_field(v).get_internal_type()})
qs is the query set. How could I add field_value??

Comment: could you edit please your original question with the following code and the problem? I would be happy to help you but it's really difficult to understand like this...

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two the same keys in a dictionary. Try something like:

```
thisdict =  {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "first_year": 1964
}
thisdict["second_year"] = 2018
```

Comment: I understand that you are trying to say the keys are unique in a dict but that does not make it similar to a set.

Comment: Well, what I meant is that they both are not letting you to have the same key for more than one time. this is a similarity between them.

Comment: Sets only have values, no keys. Like I said I understand this and I am sure you do too, but someone who does not know the difference will get the wrong idea. A dict has two parts - a key and a value. The keys are unique, the values need not be. In a set there are only values. Set maintains that the values it has are unique.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the data in the dictionary you can use following approch:

```
final_data=[]
list1=list()
print(type(final_data))
thisdict =  {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
}

thisdict["year"] = 2018
for i in thisdict:
    list1.append(thisdict[i])
final_data.append(list1)
list1=[]

thisdict["year"]=2019
for i in thisdict:
    list1.append(thisdict[i])
final_data.append(list1)

print(final_data)
```

output:

```
[['Ford', 'Mustang', 2018], ['Ford', 'Mustang', 2019]]
```